# How do you set O.E.M. System Information with a Sysprep Answer File?

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

There are a couple of entries in the Windows Registry involving hardware information that is pulled from the BIOS during the installation of Windows. These are stored in the following key:

```
HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS
```

These entries default to motherboard manufacturer information but some of the entries stay as

> To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Which of these entries can I explicitly set with Sysprep Components and which Components should I define?

Comment: You should defined those enteries you feel should be contain your information.

Comment: those data are read from the SMBIOS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS). The Motherboard vendor should include the data. Contact them for an BIOS update.

Comment: Is it possible to override these values? The MB Manufacturer (MSI in this case) does not seem to have any tool to edit the SMBIOS. Is this standard?